# Fazer com que as colunas de uma CrossTab tenham uma largura dinâmica | JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Estou trabalhando com `DynamicJasper` para gerar um relatório com uma CrossTab com colunas dinâmicas, mas estou tendo um problema, a tabela que está gerando está excedendo o limite de largura da página e algumas colunas estão sendo cortadas da tabela, mas as colunas têm um tamanho desproporcional, o que eu quero é que não importa quantas colunas ou quão grandes sejam os textos das colunas, o `Jasper` reduza automaticamente a largura das colunas até que estejam todas visíveis, mas não encontrei nada até agora que possa me ajudar com isso, tanto pelo `DynamicJasper` quanto pelo `Jasper` puro. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Code:

```
    /*
      Create an empty report (no columns)!
     */
    final FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
    drb.setPageSizeAndOrientation(new Page(582, 854, false))
        .setPrintColumnNames(false)
        .setUseFullPageWidth(true)
        .setWhenNoData("No data for this report", null)
        .setDefaultStyles(this.titleStyle, null, null, null)
        .setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    final DJCrosstab djcross = new CrosstabBuilder()
        .setHeight(582)
        .setWidth(854)
        .setHeaderStyle(this.mainHeaderStyle)
        .setDatasource("sr", DJConstants.DATA_SOURCE_ORIGIN_PARAMETER, DJConstants.DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_COLLECTION)
        .setUseFullWidth(false)
        .setColorScheme(DJConstants.COLOR_SCHEMA_LIGHT_GREEN)
        .setAutomaticTitle(false)
        .setCellBorder(Border.THIN())
        .addRow("Product Line", "productLine", String.class.getName(), false) // Y
        .addColumn("Branch", "branch", String.class.getName(), false) // X
        .addColumn("Item", "item", String.class.getName(), false) // X
        .addMeasure("amount", Float.class.getName(), DJCalculation.SUM, "Amount",
            this.measureStyle)
        .setRowStyles(this.colAndRowHeaderStyle, this.totalStyle, this.totalHeaderStyle)
        .setColumnStyles(this.colAndRowHeaderStyle, this.totalStyle, this.totalHeaderStyle)
        .setColumnHeaderHeight(30)
        .setRowHeaderWidth(50)
        .setIgnoreWidth(true)
        .setBottomSpace(0)
        .setTopSpace(0)
        .build();

    drb.addHeaderCrosstab(djcross); //add the crosstab in the header band of the report
    final DynamicReport dynamicReport = drb.build();

    //put a collection in the parameters map to be used by the crosstab
    this.params.put("sr", 
    SortUtils.sortCollection(TestRepositoryProducts.getDummyCollection(), djcross));

    final JasperDesign jasperDesign = generateJasperDesign(dynamicReport);
    final JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
    final JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, this.params, getDataSource());
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);    //finally display the report report
```

Atualmente está gerando um relatório como este (imagem abaixo), como você pode ver algumas colunas estão faltando neste relatório, essas colunas foram cortadas porque ultrapassaram o limite de largura da página.
[image: report]

Quero dizer que se for necessário parar de usar DynamicJasper para que isso seja possível, eu paro.